# Continuity of a function

Tags: analysis

> For all $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ a function $f$ satisfies $f (x+y)=f (x)\cdot f (y)$.
>
> If $f$ is continuous  at a point $a$, then show that  $f$ is  continuous  on $\mathbb R$ and  $f (x)= b^x$ for some constant  $b$.

**My approach**

$$f (1)=f (1+0)=f (1)\cdot f (0)$$
Thus $f(0)=1$ and $$f(x+h)-f (x)= f(x)\,(f (h)-1)$$

I can prove the continuity  of the function.
How can I prove that $f (x)=b^x$ for any $x\in\Bbb R$?

Comment: See also the rest of the topic overview: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/423492/87023

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

From the continuity of $f$ and $f(0)=1$, show that $f(1) > 0$. Then show that for any rational number $r$, we have $$f(r) = f(1)^r$$

Comment: I can prove that for any natural  number n f (n) =f (1)^n

Comment: But i cant get how to prove  this any real number r

Comment: @AnilKumarPandey  Note that $$f(\frac{n}{m}) = f(\frac{1}{m})^n $$ On the other hand, from the functional equation $$f(\frac{1}{m})^m = f(1)$$ So $f(r) = f(1)^r$ for any rational number $r$. This extends to all $r\in \mathbb{R}$ because $f$ is continuous.

Comment: thanks for valuable  suggestions  it really helped me